# How to access mono native code using php

Tags: c#, php, mono, shared-libraries, aot

Ahead of Time Compilation or AOT is a feature of the Mono runtime code generator.

mono --aot program.exe

This will generate a file called "program.exe.so"

- How can i load this shared object file in php script and access the class objects and  methods. ?

Thanks

Comment: Give a look at http://php.net/COM

Comment: @NeeL that wont work with mono, esp on linux (he gets a .so file)

Answer (score 0):

The native library still needs to be loaded inside an AppDomain (i.e. the Mono VM/runtime) in order to run, it is **not** a native library as such.

If you **must** I'd suggest looking at

- whether php supports COM interop (I don't use php, but I'd reckon the chance exists). This would be good since you could use that and profit from OO interface exposure
- Use Swig which has [support for C#](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#CSharp) some time now
- Alternatively, use [`mkbundle`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkbundle), and/or create a native shared library that [embeds a Mono VM](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono). The shared library wrrap around the C# interface using a "C" native API's.

Answer (score 0):

The [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/) project should be able to do this. You can compile your php code with mono and also integrate with .net from php.